# Stop browser from jumping to #name when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form in a jQuery dialog box named "login". In JavaScript, I detect if "#login" is in the URL -- if so, it displays the login dialog box. In FF/Safari/Chrome it works fine, but in IE6/7 the browser page jumps down to the top of the form when the dialog box is displayed. I would like to prevent this from happening.

I found what looked like an answer to my question [here](http://blog.rebeccamurphey.com/2007/12/04/anchor-based-url-navigation-with-jquery/), which gives this example code:

```
$('a.anchor').remove().prependTo('body');
```

I changed "a.anchor" to "form.anchor", but it doesn't work correctly. When I first load mydomain/#login IE still jumps down to the top of the form. Then if I refresh the page it again displays the dialog box but doesn't jump down.

Any idea how to globally just prevent IE from jumping to any form/anchor names?

Comment: Is there a special reason why you use the hash sign to implement functionality *other than* jumping to a document position? I mean... That's what it is for, so don't complain when it works as designed. :)

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using a query parameter or something, like page.html?showlogin=true.  The page.html#xxxxx on a URL is meant to scroll the browser to that ID on the page.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp halfway down explains the name attribute.

Otherwise you'll be doing some messy hacks to get around browsers doing what they are supposed to do.

Answer (score 3):

........ don't put the named anchors you don't want used in your code?

Comment: The form has to have a name so it can be submitted correctly.

Comment: So why not use a query parameter?

Comment: @CMB: So change the name of the form to "loginForm", that should stop #login from scrolling to it. Or change #login to #showLogin and keep the form named "login".

Answer (score 0):

There are legitimate reasons to use the hash mark this way. In Ajaxian applications it can help manage the browser history.

All browsers, including IE, should be ignoring the location.hash unless there is a named anchor -- except that IE likes to jump down to any element with that ID or NAME. So if you have

```
<form name="login" ...
```

or

```
<form id="login" ...
```

or even

```
<div id="login"><form name="somethingElse"...
```

that might cause IE to treat it like the traditional hash mark and jump down.